# Using an extended ArrayList in Google App Engine Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm creating an endpoint for Google App Engine and I've come across the need to create a custom `ArrayList` for simplicity, but I seem to be having trouble.

If I use something like this, everything is fine

```
public class MyClass {
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Person> People;
    // etc
}
```

If I switch this to

```
public class PersonList extends ArrayList<Person> {
    // custom methods
}

public class MyClass {
    @ElementCollection
    private PersonList People;
    // etc
}
```

I get the error

> PersonList is not a supported property type.

Must I stick with the first implementation for everything, or is there a way to extend a List class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I assume you just made a typo in your *question*, where you define the class as `PeopleList` and then declare a member variable of type `PersonList` ... right?

If your **code** doesn't also have that mistake, then perhaps you could use this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Person> People;
    // etc
}
```

which allows you to make the `@ElementCollection` work, but then when you **instantiate** `People`, use this:

```
People = new PersonList();
```

where `PersonList` is:

```
public class PersonList extends ArrayList<Person> {
   // custom methods
}
```

How well that works for you might depend on whether you're extending `ArrayList` just to do some **internal** bookkeeping, or if you want to add more `public` methods to its interface, to be called from within `MyClass`.  If it's the latter, then clearly that would require you to do some casting, as `People` is declared to be of type `List<Person>`, although we know it to be a `PersonList` in this case, too:

```
((PersonList)People).somePersonListMethod();
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of the casting way to do this, but I'm guessing that'll work. I'll verify once I'm able to check later on today. Thank you

Comment: What is the typo in my question exactly? I'd like to know if I'm doing something egregious.

Comment: Ahh, it's a typo. I looked at my question 20 times and didn't see it. Thank you for the answer